# Deep q learning - Defining state for snake game

Tags: python-3.x, keras, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to solve the snake game using an AI. I am not sure if I have defined the state in the right way.
For the state I have considered an array of size 24.

1. First 8 value has the distance between the snake head and wall
2. Second 8 values has the distance between between the snake head and snake body(if any).
3. Last 8 values has the distance between the snake head and food.

Please do help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are the distances 8-dimensional vectors?

Comment: I am looking at only 8 directions.(Left , left top , left bottom, top , bottom , right , right top , right bottom).@nsidn98

Comment: I still do not get how is the distance between the snake head and the wall an 8-dimensional vector. Anyways, why don't you use the image (2D array) as your state?

Comment: I am considering only the distances in 8 direction. The problem with considering 2D array is that it takes lot of time to train the object and it occupies a lot of memory space. The number of possible states is also higher. For example lets consider snake game in 5*5 grid. So initially there are 25 possible positions. And each position can have a food , snake head or snake body. So number of possible positions is 25^3 which is very big and if consider grid of 20*20 the possible states are 400^3. So this method is not preferred. @nsidn98

Comment: There are a lot of papers which use images as their states. Also they use 200x150 RGB videos at 60Hz. You can refer [this](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vmnih/docs/dqn.pdf) paper.